# typescript inform compiler about which union type is being used

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Suppose I have the following type:

```
type TMyType = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d?: SpecialTypeA | SpecialTypeB | SpecialTypeC;
}
```

How do I tell typescript that in my (React) child components I know of which type d is?
I am looking for something like `data={data} as TMyType <SpecialTypeB>`.
In case this is not possible, what would be the best and most easy to understand solution, since a lot in our team are new to using typescript

**Solution** as per AKX suggested:

```
type TMyType<T extends SpecialTypeA | SpecialTypeB | SpecialTypeC> = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d?: T;
}
```

and for my reaction parent component:

```
<ChildComponent data = {data as TMyType<SpecialTypeA>}/>
```

and inside the child component

```
interface IProps {
  data: TMyType<SpecialTypeA> 
}
```

Comment: Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBzz4N) work for you?  Do you need to leave `TMyType` alone or can you modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just rewrite the type as

```
type TMyType<T> = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  c: number;
  d?: T;
}
```

You could make that `<T extends A | B | C>` if you want to constrain the type of T.

Comment: and you want to preserve `TMyType` being used without type parameters, you could make `T` [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to `A | B | C`.  Not sure if the optionality of `d` is an issue either

Comment: works like a charm. I updated my answer to include your solution for react components. If you could double check I understood you correctly, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: @leviathan Glad I could help. You can also make the props type generic over T and you won't need the cast at all...

Comment: @AKX sorry to bother you with this, but as you probably figured by now I am also new to typescript ;) What do you mean with ur last comment?

Comment: not needing the cast would be great though. because i have general components, where I just know the data is of type TMyType<T>, but since I use these for all possible T types, I cannot specify the type in these

Comment: The best I have so far in my generic components (where T can be any) is
`interface IProps<T>{data?: TMyType<T>}`  and then `const MyComponent = ({data}:IProps<SpecialTypeA> | <SpecialTypeB> | <SpecialTypeC>)`

Comment: and since you already solved the question asked in this, I created a new question with a codesandbox example to make it more clear: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482506/typescript-how-to-use-a-generic-type-which-is-specified-lateron