# Typescript how to use a generic type which is specified later on?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

First of all: This is the first time I made a CodeSandbox to create a simplified example. Any suggestions on how to improve this are welcome!

**The issue:**
I want to present animal facts. Some facts are shared among all animals, while others are animal specific. In my main component `App`, I do not know the type yet. So I want to keep it on the generic `Animal` level. Some magic happens (pretty much just an API call) in my main component and now I know the type. This yields in me rendering a specific `Animal` component. These specific components have more general components on their own, and, of course, some specific animal data.
Now I just cannot wrap my head around on how to do this properly with typescript.  The codesandbox should clear things up: As you can see, the compiler is giving me a hard time, because the type `Animal` is unknown. And right so. How do I solve this?  I am still learning typescript, so if my general approach to this is unwise, I am happy for suggestions on how else to structure this.

[Codesandbox to make it more understandable](https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-burnell-tgldo?file=/src/App.tsx)

And for those who prefer the code type here, here it is:

General App:

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<TFact<Animal>>();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hi there</h1>
      {/* This is part of a switch case, I know at this point
      what kind of animal to render */}
      <Cat data={data} />
      {/*<Dog data={data} />*/}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Two examples of child components:

```
interface IProps {
  data: TFact<TCat>;
}

const Cat = ({ data }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GeneralChild data={data} />
      Meow!
    </div>
  );
};

export default Cat;
```

And the second one:

```
interface IProps {
  data: TFact<TDog>;
}

const Dog = ({ data }: IProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <GeneralChild data={data} />
      Woof!
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dog;
```

General Child:

```
interface IProps {
  data: TFact<Animal>;
}

const GeneralChild = ({ data: IProps }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      Well I can be anything! And that is okay, because I only need the data
      shared by all components!
    </div>
  );
};

export default GeneralChild;
```

and the most relevant, the typing:

```
export type TFact<Animal extends TCat | TDog | TDuck> = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  animalSpecificDetails: Animal;
};

export type TCat = {
  randomFact1: string;
  randomFact2: string;
  feelsLikeaGod: boolean;
};

export type TDog = {
  randomFact1: string;
  randomFact2: string;
  alwaysLoyal: boolean;
};

export type TDuck = {
  randomFact1: string;
  randomFact2: string;
  sound: string;
};
```

Comment: From your example, it looks like `Animal` is not actually defined. The only instance I'm seeing it when `Animal` is used as a generic, i.e. `Animal extends TCat | TDog | TDuck`. In this case, there's no actual definition since Animal is treated like a variable (`T`). This means it's only relative to that particular definition. You'll need to define it (either a type, interface, or class) and export it for other files to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the data you can use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) to figure out what type you have by examining its properties.  The [`in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) is a built-in typeguard.  If there is a property `"feelsLikeaGod" in animal` then we have a `TCat` and so on.

```
function doCatThing(cat: TCat) { }
function doDogThing(dog: TDog) { }
function doDuckThing(duck: TDuck) { }

function myFunc(animal: TCat | TDog | TDuck) {
    if ("feelsLikeaGod" in animal) {
        doCatThing(animal);  // animal has type TCat
    } else if ("alwaysLoyal" in animal) {
        doDogThing(animal); // animal has type TDog
    } else {
        // don't even need to check the last case because TDuck is the only possibility
        doDuckThing(animal); // animal has type TDuck
    }
}
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wOaa6m)

Unfortunately this doesn't work as nicely when we are checking a property on a nested object like `data.animalSpecificDetails` on `TFact<TCat | TDog | TDuck>`.

This works because because typescript will refine the type for `data.animalSpecificDetails`:

```
if ("alwaysLoyal" in data.animalSpecificDetails) {
  return <Dog data={{...data, animalSpecificDetails: data.animalSpecificDetails}}/>
}
```

But this doesn't work because typescript does not apply those refinements to the parent object:

```
if ("alwaysLoyal" in data.animalSpecificDetails) {
  return <Dog data={data}/>
}
```

We could use an assertion to keep things concise:

```
if ("feelsLikeaGod" in data.animalSpecificDetails) {
  return <Cat data={data as TFact<TCat>} />
}
```

But you need to be careful that any assertions that you make are correct.  You open yourself up to run-time errors by making assertions that aren't guaranteed.

You could define your own [user-defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to check the parent `TData` object.

By the way, @Dom's comment is totally correct that `Animal` does not exist as a type outside the scope of the `TFact`.  `Animal` is just the name for that type's `T`.  You should define `Animal` either as the base object `{randomFact1: string; randomFact2: string;}` or as the union `TCat | TDog | TDuck`.  My personal preference is for the base object.

```
// All animals have these properties
type Animal = {
    randomFact1: string;
    randomFact2: string;
}

// T is the generic variable for this type
// You can call the variable anything, but I changed it to T to be clearer about what it is
export type TFact<T extends Animal> = {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    animalSpecificDetails: T;
};

// We don't need to repeat as much because we can use Animal
export type TCat = Animal & {
    feelsLikeaGod: boolean;
};
```

So our type guard would look like this.  We have a `TFact` for any `Animal` and we say that if this is true, it's a `TFact` for a `TCat`.

```
const isCatFact = (fact: TFact<Animal>): fact is TFact<TCat> => {
    return "feelsLikeaGod" in fact.animalSpecificDetails;
}
```

So there's lost of ways to handle this.  I do want to give you some working code so here is one way.  I am checking the properties on the `data.animalSpecificDetails` object, which I have named `animal`, and I am combining the guarded `animal` value with the rest of the `data` object.

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState<TFact<TCat | TDog | TDuck>>();

    const renderAnimal = () => {
        // skip undefined
        if (!data) {
            return;
        }
        //just so we don't have to write data.animalSpecificDetails every time
        const animal = data.animalSpecificDetails;
        // cat
        if ("feelsLikeaGod" in animal) {
            return <Cat data={{ ...data, animalSpecificDetails: animal }} />
        }
        // dog
        else if ("alwaysLoyal" in animal) {
            return <Dog data={{ ...data, animalSpecificDetails: animal }} />
        }
        // duck
        else {
            return <Duck data={{ ...data, animalSpecificDetails: animal }} />
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Hi there</h1>
            {renderAnimal()}
        </div>
    );
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w188YW)

Comment: Thank you for this.  
I think I worded my overall question poorly.  
What I am trying to achieve is that in most of my components I can just use `data: TFact<Animal>`
and then access it with `data.randomFact1`,  not `data.animalSpecific.randomFact1`.
So I guess what I am looking for is to build a general component which works for all and which accepts a generic that says "I can be any of the subclasses, it doesnt matter" and typescript makes sure I only use properties which are type independent in these components

Comment: You have provided a solution to the question though and thank you for that :)
I made a new ticket for this comment, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66489072/typescript-placeholder-generic
If you are interested