# Typescript Placeholder Generic

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Suppose the given data

```
const dataA = {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  attributes: {specificA: "hello", specificA2: 14, nonspecific:"Well"},
}

const dataB = {
  name: "Lisa",
  age: 38,
  attributes: {specificB: "hello", someMoreSpecificStuff: true, nonspecific:"Hope this"},
}

const dataC = {
  name: "Peter",
  age: 60,
  attributes: {specificC: "hello", couldBeAnyName: "Oh My", nonspecific:"makes sense"},
}
```

Some of my components will only access the general information (`name`, `age`)
Some others will only access the general information, but also the general information that is shared in properties whose keys are the same, but the values are not (`attributes.nonspecific`)
Some components will work only one of the data types.

What I came up so far is this:

```
const dataA: MyDataType<A> = {
  name: "John",
  age: 25,
  attributes: {specificA: "hello", specificA2: 14, nonspecific:"Well"},
}

const dataB: MyDataType<B> = {
  name: "Lisa",
  age: 38,
  attributes: {specificB: "hello", someMoreSpecificStuff: true, nonspecific:"Hope this"},
}

const dataC:MyDataType<C> = {
  name: "Peter",
  age: 60,
  attributes: {couldBeAnything: "Oh My", nonspecific:"makes sense"},
}

type MyDataType<T extends A | B | C> = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  attributes: T
}

type A = {
  specificA: string;
  specificA2: number;
  nonspecific: string;
}

type B = {
  specificB: string;
  someMoreSpecificStuff: true;
  nonspecific: string;
}

type C = {
  couldBeAnything: string;
  nonspecific: string;
}
```

This works fine, but if I now want a component to work with any of these data types, I have to type it like this:

```
interface ForMyGeneralComponent{
  data: MyDataType<A | B | C>
}
```

what I would like to write is

```
interface ForMyGeneralComponent{
      data: MyDataType<GenericType>
    }
```

and declare somewhere that `GenericType` is either `A`, `B` or `C`.

Why you ask? Imagine these attributes can be made of up 30 different types. If I have to type them out everywhere, this decreases readability by a lot. And also I am lazy I guess?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggggLhgWQJ4BEkIAq2ADgKYA8KAfDALwwDeAUDDGAgLZkYBEAUiAAWYXgBpWMBAHMeMAEwBWCWyRQATgEsARgFcoZCBkYRywTQDNNwdDF5CyAG0chxMU2XNWb8jAEYAFjF2cA8vazReAHUnR14AXwl45mZQSFhEZAAhDBx8ZGJyCizaBhY2Dm4%20ABlNCARxSRk5AGYADhUpKA0dfUNjMMtrHLsHZ1dgiBBuTBB1MgBlMyHgBahdCwsMDV0yYLBQ5e9IgAkQchgoITqEpJS06HgCAGE0PIJCymfSpklKuV4AAUyAZ1I1VLIMAA2AAMnTUWj0BiMTFAukccCyZBQYGwV00YGkfAA8kIsNg3AdIEcIrxOAgANaGdxkSBkW7MZLMKCkMjk-JEXkUQgwMgADwMYDgEBgKBgAB8YFkFTBvvRfhUuHJoFpCQBuJqQ9i6TjaMjqA2qbqIvoowiclI8i5ysqSQbeWw6gnSS3uGk%20DBgE1mi1-Q6eFYYL36h3c3lK9XlP0R7wjaM%20t3TMizeZLFPWNYbLaXdS7X1U90Rdw9GNcp1856JyRojFYnF466EqM1jMVcPhYDd3UZrkE0EWBDAPkAMTmOAA4qzzQhHM9piRwKyoEnMghcngPkK5YrlYrvpygA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, if I understood your use-case.
Maybe you just want to introduce a new type for all your attributes e.g.

```ts
type MyAttributes = A | B | C;

type MyDataType<T extends MyAttributes> = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  attributes: T
}

interface ForMyGeneralComponent{
  data: MyDataType<MyAttributes>
}
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Do I even need the extends?
Wouldn't it be easier to just have
`type MyDataType<MyAttributes>` ?
Do I gain anything by the `extends`?

Comment: you get type-safety for `dataA.attributes.xx`

Answer (score 1):

> So I guess what I am looking for is to build a general component which works for all and which accepts a generic that says "I can be any of the subclasses, it doesnt matter" and typescript makes sure I only use properties which are type independent in these components

Per your comment on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66482506/typescript-how-to-use-a-generic-type-which-is-specified-lateron/66487241?noredirect=1#comment117541423_66487241), you are definitely over-complicating this!  If you have some components which take any of the subtypes then you don't need a generic or a union for that.  All you need is define the parts which are universal.

```
type GeneralType = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  attributes: {
    nonspecific: string;
  }
}
```

This doesn't *have* to be a generic, but we can make it a generic to make it easier to create the specific versions.  You can set a default value for the generic variable if no value is provided.  So we want a type that in its default state will be the `GeneralType` above, but can also be used to create `A` data, `B` data, etc.

My advice is that the generic variable should refer only to the properties that change.  I would not include `nonspecific: string` in the generic portion because it is always present.

Here I am using the generic `Extra` to refer to all `attributes` other than `nonspecific`.

```
type MyDataType<Extra extends {} = {}> = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  attributes: Extra & {
    nonspecific: string;
  }
}
```

Just leave off the `Extra` in the general case and it will use the default which is an empty object (no extra properties).

```
interface ForMyGeneralComponent {
  data: MyDataType;
}
```

```
const dataGeneral: MyDataType = {
  name: "Peter",
  age: 60,
  attributes: {nonspecific:"makes sense"},
}
```

Your specific cases are still mostly the same as before, `const dataA: MyDataType<A>` etc., but now you don't need to include `nonspecific` in `A`, `B`, and `C`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wgrr4W)

Comment: It's attempting to overcomplicate things, your answer is very helpful!